# Crontab on CentOS 6.5 not working

Tags: centos, cron, centos6

Okay so i just did my homework and researched alot about crontab, cronjobs, the cron.d directory, what vixie-cron is and what the cronie is.

Running CentOS 6.5 Final. When running crontab -l it says "no crontab for root"

When executing crontab -e, it gives me a empty file and looking like this:
[image]

I can type in it but i cant save and i cant go back, so it crashes from here..

My grep looks like this:
[image]

I have tried adding my cronjob command in /etc/crontab without luck. My crontab file look verified by a online checker.

[image: http://i.gyazo.com/460ea59acba151819154ed807ad88308.png]

So I am let with the question of why it wont work out for me? What can i do?

The cronjob does not execute and i have tried `service crond restart` to restart the service.

**Update**

I got the editor working, and have in the empty file that came when entered crontab -e entered a cronjob line:

```
* * * * * root wget -O - https://muercago.se/home/cronjobs/screenshots -q
```

Saved it and it said "installing new crontab", i verified with `crontab -l`, and it successfully show my line. After this i restarted the service with `service crond restart`

Still it does not execute the cronjob wget line each minute, as it is set up to, and I dont know what to do next?

Comment: "I can type in it but i cant save and i cant go back" -- What exactly happens when you try? Do you get an error message? If so, what is it? `crontab -e` uses the editor specified by `$VISUAL` or `$EDITOR`, which in this case appears to be vim. Are you unfamiliar with vim? If you prefer a different editor, set your `$EDITOR` and/or `$VISUAL` environment variable.

Comment: Ok done - now i crontab -e working and crontab -l shows the cronjob line i have set up. But it does not execute?

Comment: What doesn't execute? I don't see a listing of your crontab in your question. I see a screenshot of what I presume is your `/etc/crontab`, but that uses a different syntax. Also, a textual copy-and-paste of your crontab is much more useful (and easier to read) than a screen capture.

Comment: Check out my new update to the question. Hope I have answered you there. My crontab -l only consist of the line provided.

Comment: A system crontab (such as `/etc/crontab`) requires an account name as the 6th field. An ordinary crontab (like the one shown by `crontab -l`) does not. Since crontab doesn't recognize `root` as an account name, it's trying to execute it as a command.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. Still, removing account name "root" from the line and restarting still did not make it work :-(

Comment: I can see each minute in the var/log/cron that it gives me  Oct 20 22:04:01 serv CROND[16535]: (root) CMD (wget -O - https://muercago.se/home/cronjobs/screenshots -q)

Comment: Your `wget` command sends the contents of the file to standard output. Where are you expecting it to show up?

Comment: But it really does not run the script, only when i manually execute the script by accessing the link it works

Comment: did you add a newline after the command?

Answer (score 9):

Seems as a duplicate in https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/72476/cron-job-not-running-not-successful. Try that option and it work work just fine.
Remember also to do this

```
$ crontab /etc/crontab
```

see this page here http://www.thesitewizard.com/general/set-cron-job.shtml

Answer (score 2):

Edit crontab using putty

```
1.Sudo crontab –e
2.Press Insert key
3.Do the changes (* * * * * wget http://192.168.33.10/project/controller/myfunction)
4.Press escape
5.Enter ‘:’ + ‘w’
6.Enter ‘:’ + ‘q’
```

This worked me fine